# docker-compose inside VSCode - fails to run pwsh script. but dockerfile works ok

Tags: docker, powershell, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, microsoft-graph-api

**Background Information**

I am trying to use Microsoft's powershell graph api docker image to run some scripts inside a container against my Azure tenant.  Ultimately, in addition to create and deleting resources from my tenant, I need these scripts to call a web API running on the host machine.  So instead of just using a Dockerfile, I started with a docker-compose.yml so I can define any specific network config that might be needed. I also forsee the need to create a database container down the line, so docker-compose is the way i want to go.

**What's Not Working**

When i try to right click on the docker-compose.yml and "Compose Up" from the context menu, I can se that it builds the container.  From the docker desktop if i check out the logs, I see this error:

```
2023-04-26 15:55:47 ./userSync/createUserAndSync.ps1: The term './userSync/createUserAndSync.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
2023-04-26 15:55:47 Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

My dev environment is as follows:

- ide is vscode
- windows 11 pro for host machine
- docker desktop version 4.17.0
- docker engine v20.10.23

This is what my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  msgraph-pwsh:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/microsoftgraph/powershell:latest
    build: .
    working_dir: /workspaces/mpj/server/AutomatedTest
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
      - 12345:12345
      - 7071:7071
    command: pwsh -c "./userSync/createUserAndSync.ps1"
```

And this is what the devcontainer.json file looks like:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.231.6/containers/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
  "name": "GraphApiPwsh",

  // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
  //"context": "..",
  //"dockerFile": "./Dockerfile",
  "dockerComposeFile": ["docker-compose.yml"],
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/mpj/server/AutomatedTest",
  "service": "msgraph-pwsh",
  "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",

  // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
  //"settings": {},

  // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
  //"extensions": [],

  // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
  "forwardPorts": [7071, 80, 443, 12345],

  // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing curl.
  "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl"

  // Uncomment when using a ptrace-based debugger like C++, Go, and Rust
  // "runArgs": [ "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE", "--security-opt", "seccomp=unconfined" ],
  //"runArgs": ["--network=host"]
  // Uncomment to use the Docker CLI from inside the container. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/samples/docker-from-docker.
  // "mounts": [ "source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock,type=bind" ],

  // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user if you've added one. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
  // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

**What I've tried So far**

If I just use a Dockerfile like this:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/microsoftgraph/powershell:latest
```

Change my devcontainer.json to comment out all docker-compose settings and just use DOckerfile like this:

```
{
  "name": "GraphApiPwsh",

  // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
  //"context": "..",
  "dockerFile": "./Dockerfile",
  //"dockerComposeFile": ["docker-compose.yml"],
  //"workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/pwshGraphApi",
  //"service": "msgraph-pwsh",
  //"shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
```

And then I use the 'Reopen in Container' option in vscode docker is happy.  I then use Terminal -> New Terminal in vscode and it dumps me into a bash terminal.  From here I can do this:

```
root@ffc790e619be:/workspaces/mpj/server/AutomatedTests# pwsh -c "./userSync/createUserAndSync.ps1"
```

And the script runs just fine.
I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.  If you can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.